# I need a way to remove some strings in a link

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am working on an application whereby I am inserting url from the database into the anchor tag, which works well, but the issue is that there is a translation in the application whereby there is `/en/ or //ar` in the link which i would like to remove.

models.py

```
class Announcement_by_dean(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager)
    message = models.TextField()
    Attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='announcement', blank=True, null=True)
    sent_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "message sent to " + ', '.join([i.student_ID for i in self.student_id.all()]) + " on " + str(self.sent_date)
```

views.py

```
def student_course_list(request):

    stu_course_id = request.POST.get('stu_course_id')

    stdnt = add_students_by_manager.objects.get(student_ID=request.session['Stu_id'])
    my_announcement = Announcement_by_dean.objects.filter(student_id=stdnt.pk).order_by('-id')

    context = {"my_announcement":my_announcement}

    return render(request, 'student_course_list.html', context)
```

student_course_list.html

```
    {% for x in my_announcement %}
    <div class="card container mt-4 mb-5">
      <h5 class="card-header">From: the dean</h5>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="media/{{x.Attachment}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">View file</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

The link `URL` is `http://localhost:8000/en/media/announcement/charts-sparklines.html` but i would like to remove the `/en/ or /ar/` in it. I want the final URL format to be `http://localhost:8000/media/announcement/charts-sparklines.html`

Comment: On what side(server or client) do you want to get this done?

Comment: anyone of the server or client is okay by me

Comment: i think client-side is better

Comment: I think just adding a slash at the start of your url should be enough? `/media/{{x.Attachment}}`? Also what is x? And why don't you simply use `your_model_instance.file_field.url`?

Comment: since you have a loop in there, its better you format your string from the server side, you may do that before composing your context dictionary. Solving this on the client-side may require sending your context dictionary as JSON through ajax, then run a string replace method on each element of the response object before displaying the result in html

Comment: @SeyiDaniel can you please make an illustration on how i can go about that.

Comment: can your share your django view for the endpoint?

Comment: okay, i will do that

Comment: Do note that there is a difference between a url starting with a slash and one without... In your example if you are on the page `http://localhost:8000/en/` you would end up on `http://localhost:8000/en/media/{{x.Attachment}}` because you write your url as `media/{{x.Attachment}}`, whereas if you write `/media/{{x.Attachment}}` with a **leading** slash this would not even be an issue as you would then end up at `http://localhost:8000/media/{{x.Attachment}}`...

Comment: you can use a regular expression to find and replace a pattern in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as stated in my comment you should add a leading slash to your url like `href="/media/{{x.Attachment}}"` (absence of leading slash means the url is relative to the **current url** and not starting from the domain itself). Secondly since Attachment is a file field you can simply get it's url by writing `{{x.Attachment.url}}` so your anchor tag would end up being:

```
<a href="{{ x.Attachment.url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">View file</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use simple string formatting methods.

```
a = "http://localhost:8000/en/media/announcement/charts-sparklines.html"
a[0:a.find("/en")] + a[a.find("/en")+3:]
>> 'http://localhost:8000/media/announcement/charts-sparklines.html'
```

Also what purpose does the templates.html have for your question?

Comment: the templates.html is just a file that renders to the screen

Comment: how am I able to use this method in my HTML file because I think this is a simple python script. I think there should be some javascript method that can be used and thus injected into the template.